# Galois group and solvable by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, radicals, splitting-field

I came across the following problem in an old qualifying exam which states:

Show that the irreducible $h(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is solvable by radicals if $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=25$ where $K$ is the splitting field of $h(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My approach was to consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a real root of $h(x)$. Now we get that $25=[K:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$. How do we proceed from here without knowing what the degree of $\alpha$ is? I want to eventually show that the Galois group is solvable.

Comment: Do you know that the order of the Galois group is the degree of the splitting field?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Yes! I think I have got it. Since the order of the Galois group is $25$ it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$. In either case the group is solvable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A group with $25$ elements is abelian, hence solvable.